# Error message when trying to calculate functional diversity using hillR

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate functional diversity using hill_func in the hillR package.

```
sp.data.fore <- data.frame(fore_sp_data_for_fun_analysis_)
trait.data.fore <-data.frame(fore_lake_diatom_fun_traits_EDITED_numbers)

hill_func(comm= sp.data.fore, traits =trait.data.fore)
```

I am getting this error message:

```
Error in FD::gowdis(x = traits, asym.bin = NULL, ord = ord) : 
  Binary variables should be of class 'numeric'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In hill_func(comm = sp.data.fore, traits = trait.data.fore) : 
 There are species from community data that are not on traits matrix
            Delete these species from comm data...

2: In hill_func(comm = sp.data.fore, traits = trait.data.fore) : 
 There are species in the traits data not in the communit data

                Delete these species from trait data...
```

I have double checked that the species data are correct in both datasets, and even copied and pasted the species names directly from one to the other to ensure accuracy. The community data are in sites in rows and species in columns and the trait data are in species in rows and traits in columns are directed on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hillR/hillR.pdf

I also do not understand the error in the built in gowdis in hillR, as this works when I do it separately in the FD package and I do not have any binary variables.
Any help is appreciated!! Thanks